# Error node:events:498 - Server listening but with the error message

Tags: node.js, debugging

I am practising the node js HTTP method. The server response is there but nodemon is getting crashed each time I called. When I restart the node app and get a response from server below error message is shown. I have deleted node modules, cleared cache, and did npm install nothing worked for me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYdFD.png)

```
const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === '/') {
    res.end('Home Page')
  }
  if (req.url === '/about') {
    
    res.end('About Page')
  }
  res.end('Error Page')
})

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port : 5000...')
})`
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `res.end('Home Page')` and `res.end('Error Page')` will be executed in your code. Obviously, you can't call twice the `res.end` method. Put a return to each ifs.

```
if (req.url === '/') {
    res.end('Home Page')
    return
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @bmz1 it worked. while i use if,elseif and else also the error is not throwing. I got 2 ways to solve.